# Why in React Big Calender "onDropEvent" handler, "event" prop is missing "id" type in it (using Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript, react-big-calendar

"onEventDrop" handler, event prop is missing its "id" type, even though it exists in "event" data!!

```
    const handleResizeEvent:withDragAndDropProps["onEventDrop"] = (data) => {
        const {end, start, event} = data;
        console.log(event?.id, "its here but typescript saying its missing")
    }
```

though i can do "stuff" with that "id" from this "event" dataset, but typescript is still giving me "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Event'"

what am i missing here? thanks and happy coding to all :)

i tried to use "EventInteractionArgs" for "data" props but still same "typescript" error is showing up in "vscode"

i can see that "id" value is in there
[a screenshot with console in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZRDm.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the TypeScript definition does not include 'id' on an 'Event'. TypeScript definitions for Big Calendar are not maintained by the Big Calendar project.